# Oracle SQL - multilevel collection nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, oop, nested-table

Hi I am trying to create a table from OO inheritance with a nested table and keep being presented with SQL Error: ORA-00904: when I run

```
CREATE TABLE customer_tab OF customer
(PRIMARY KEY (custID))
NESTED TABLE mobilePhone STORE AS nt_mobilePhone_tab;
```

Some other SQL for background information

```
CREATE TYPE address AS OBJECT(
nameOrNum VARCHAR2(10),
street VARCHAR2(20),
city VARCHAR2(15),
postCode VARCHAR2(8)
)
not final;
/

CREATE TYPE name AS OBJECT(
title VARCHAR2(6),
firstName VARCHAR2(20),
surName VARCHAR2(20)
)
not final;
/

CREATE TYPE mobile_phone_nested AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(12);

CREATE TYPE phone AS OBJECT(
homePhone NUMBER,
mobilePhone mobile_phone_nested
)
not final;
/

CREATE TYPE people AS OBJECT(
pname NAME,
niNumber VARCHAR2(9),
paddress ADDRESS,
pphone PHONE
)
not final;
/

CREATE TYPE customer under people (
custID INTEGER
)
not final;
/

CREATE customer_type AS TABLE OF customer;

CREATE TABLE customer_table of customer
(PRIMARY KEY (custID))
NESTED TABLE customer STORE AS nt_customer_tab
(NESTED TABLE mobilePhone STORE AS nt_mobilePhone_tab);
```

Any help would be appreciated I have looked at Oracle Section 5 to no avail.

Comment: This might be helpful http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/object-views-and-nested-tables.php#NestedTable

Comment: Hi Polppan I don't think I can declare the actual nest inside the table as I am creating the customer_table of the type customer. The nest is declared in the types.

Comment: One more link [Multilevel Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96594/adobjdes.htm#452969)

Comment: Hi all just wanted to say thanks for the input.  I managed to get the nested table to work by removing it from the people type and move it into employee and customer.